# javascript this in 'static method'

Tags: javascript, this

```
Class.method = function () { this.xx }
Class.prototype.method = function () { this.xx }
var clazz = new Class();
clazz.method();
```

When I call the 4th line `this` in the function will refer to clazz
But when Class.method() is executed, what will `this` refer to?

Comment: It will refer to new object Class = new Object() or Class = function(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` within the `Class.prototype.method` function will still refer to the `Class` instance. This isn't a static method, a static (i.e. one per class) method would be something like:

```
Class.method = function () {
    // I am a static method
};
```

For example:

```
var Example = function () {
    this.name = "DefaultName";
};

Example.prototype.setName = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var test = new Example();
test.setName("foo");

console.log(test.name); // "foo"
```

Comment: Oh,so fast your answer!Sorry,may be my expression is not clear.What confused me is i think this always refers to an object instance,but Class is not an object instance.

Comment: @jlchen yes, actually Class **is** an object instance. Functions are objects.

Comment: Thank you!!! Class is also an object instance of Function [i read an article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).And i know what is first-class now O(∩_∩)O

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.method()` on your constructor function itself (without `new`), `this` will still be bound to the `Class` object. The `this` value always depends on the type of invocation, since you are calling the function from within an object (= a method), `this` will be bound to that context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class = function() {
   this.xx = "hello";
}
Class.method = function () { this.xx } 
Class.prototype.method = function () { alert(this.xx) }
var clazz=new Class();
clazz.method(); // display "hello";
Class.method() // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

it will refer to the object calling the `Class.method` function.